# Kendo UI Pie chart incase of no data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I want to show at least one circle incase of no data in piechart. Now it is disappearing if the percentage is zero. only label text is appearing.[image: Piechart with zero percentage]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Kendo provides it out of the box. Please find the workaround specified in one of the post in their forum.

[No Data message Pie chart](http://www.telerik.com/forums/no-data-message-pie-chart)